# Is it possible do download a programm FROM a microprocessor?

Tags: microprocessor, jtag

I really don't find anything on this topic. I'm not sure if JTAG may give such possibilities.

[Edit]:I found out, that for example with AVR Processors it's possible, as long as the corresponding fuse isn't set.

Comment: Please give us more details. Which processor do you have in mind? Which platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible, you have to look at the datasheet and possibly other documentation for the microcontroller (a microprocessor with separate program memory will usually have accessible memory and memory buses, it will usually be possible).

The rub is that any commercial product will usually have internal memory "locked" to prevent it from being read, so that it cannot be copied or reverse-engineered easily. To unlock it is supposed to require complete erasure of the chip, so the information will be gone.

So the answer, is "maybe, but if you have to ask, probably not".